# RGB/HEX/HSL Split 16777216 colors in basic 16 color ranges

Tags: html, css, hex, rgb, hsl

Hello i need to know **16 basic color ranges** one of these RGB or HEX or HSL.
I take example as RGB. **RGB** split in three color mix **R**-red, **G**-green **B**-blue,  each of the color have 256 color shades from 0 to 255 so in total is 256*256*256=16777216 colors. **I need this 16777216 color split in 16 ranges**

```
rgb(0,0,1)
rgb(0,0,2)
rgb(0,0..)
rgb(0,0,255)

rgb(0,1,0)
rgb(0,1,1)
rgb(0,1,..)
rgb(0,1,255) and etc
```

[image]

Comment: Could you expand on `I need this 16777216 color split in 16 ranges`? I just don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this website for this:
http://html-color-codes.info/

I use it everytime for colors :D

Comment: I can't understand what do you need... do you want show all colors? If you want this you can do a bucle with javascript

Comment: i want split in ranges like this rgb(0,0,0) = black and rgb(0,0,5) = black, so (0,0,0-5) is black, second is white rgb(255,255,255) = white and rgb (255,255,250) = white, so rgb(255,255,250-250) = white and etc.

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking, and what your problem is. What is `rgb(255,255,250-250)` supposed to mean??

Comment: i want to say from 250 to 255 last digits (250-255)

Comment: Well no, technically only 0, 0, 0 is black and only 255, 255, 255 is white.